# Can't fetch all the members of a guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make it so my bot caches every `GuildMember` of a certain guild on boot. I put the following code inside my `ready` event callback function:

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    guild.members.fetch().catch(reason => APPLICATION.logger.error(reason.stack));
});
```

It throws the following error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at C:\Users\João Teixeira\Documents\Workshop\Projects\Discord Bots\Diranui\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:420:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GuildMemberManager._fetchMany (C:\Users\João Teixeira\Documents\Workshop\Projects\Discord Bots\Diranui\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:417:12)    at GuildMemberManager.fetch (C:\Users\João Teixeira\Documents\Workshop\Projects\Discord Bots\Diranui\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:175:31)     
    at C:\Users\João Teixeira\Documents\Workshop\Projects\Discord Bots\Diranui\builds\latest\events\Ready.js:20:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Couple notes:

- I have the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent both in my client declaration and enabled in the developer's portal.
- The guild whose members I'm checking does exist and the bot is in it.

Comment: Why are you looping through the cache and then fetching the guild? If the guild is already cached theres no point in re-fetching it.

Comment: Yeah that's true @Finbar, either way I still get the same error, fetching it was kind of a desperate attempt at fixing it. I edited the question and removed that portion of the code.

Comment: Try instead: Fetching all guilds and **then** looping through the cache.

Comment: What is `APPLICATION.logger.error`?

Comment: @MrMythical Just a winston based way of logging errors

Comment: @Viriato can you include that method in the question?